# Is there a Firefox and Chrome equivalent of IE's autohiding scrollbar?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

So for IE, with the CSS

```
-ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
```

you can auto hide the scrollbar which appears if you hover over the content. Is there an equivalent way to do this in Chrome and Firefox?

I know Chrome has

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
     display: none;
```

which hides the scrollbar and allows you to scroll with keypress but that isn't the exact functionality I want. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I don't think so, since browsers other than Microsoft Edge implement their own scrollbar controls rather than using the native Windows scrollbar (and IE's implementation is, well, Windows-specific). I suspect the same comparison can be made between Firefox/Chrome and Safari on macOS.

Comment: @BoltClock, On osX browsers do use the default os ones, which auto-hide by default.

Comment: @Kaiido: Huh. The more you know. No idea why they don't do the same on Windows then.

Comment: Because osX ones are prettier ? Or at least have the same behavior in eleven last versions of the os? Because they have an openly accessible API to interact with and win doesn't ? I have no real idea... Should ask the teams.